# Please explain $.get() function to me

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http-get

```
$.get("test.php", function(data) {
    alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
});
```

What exactly can I expect to be inside the data parameter of the callback function after requesting for `test.php`?

Secondly, if I'm querying my database in `test.php`, what sort of code would I need to pass on the values of the query to the parameter data inside my callback function?

I'm confused about the connection between sending the request and what the callback function 'gains' after the request succeeds and it is executed.

Comment: It seems some ajax-like, get value function from a php file. Just a guess

Comment: Not to sound like a snub but what did you see when you executed the code? And of course what the callback function "gains" is determined by what the server sent!

Comment: Surely it took longer to write this post than to Google it and read the official documentation ...

Comment: @phpNoOb Yeah, cos guesses are really useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [official jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/), `.get()` makes an HTTP GET request to retrieve data from the server.

Since the request is client side, if you request the contents of, for example, `test.php`, the data you will receive is the output of the script *after* it has run, i.e., you will **not** receive any PHP source code in the response; the data you receive will be exactly the same as if you'd gone and visited the page directly (unless you pass additional data with the request for the page to work with).

For example if you used this code:

```
$.get("test.php", function(data) {
  alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
});
```

and your `test.php` file had these contents:

```
<?php
    echo "hello";
?>
```

then your alert would display the following text:

> Data Loaded: hello

Additionally, if you want to pass additional parameters, you can do so like this:

```
$.get("test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" }, function(data) {
    alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
});
```

And then in `test.php`:

```
echo $_GET['name'];
```

Answer (score 4):

`$.get()` makes an AJAX call to whatever URL you specify with the HTTP Method `GET`. The data returned by the server-side script is what you get in the `data` parameter of the success callback.

The `success` callback only fires after the server-side script returns a response. If the script sends `Content-Type: application/json`, then jQuery will parse the response as a JS object so that `data` is not a string, but an object.

`$.get` is just a shorthand for `$.ajax()` which allows you more granular control :

```
$.ajax({
  type: GET,
  url : 'test.php',
  success : function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

Further reading:

[jQuery.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)
[jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)
[Getting started with AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX)

Answer (score 1):

Load data from the server using a HTTP GET request.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

This is an easy way to send a simple GET request to a server without having to use the more complex $.ajax function. It allows a single callback function to be specified that will be executed when the request is complete (and only if the response has a successful response code). If you need to have both error and success callbacks, you may want to use $.ajax.

Comment: You could elaborate a little bit. I think he needs a well explained description than just a link. +1 for the good search anyway

Comment: To be clear my lack of understanding came from the assumption that return value must be nested inside a function.

Answer (score 0):

Data is from type PlainObject or String. Second part of your question is already answered.